# Bad restore file magic number when windows scheduler tries executing any R script

Tags: r, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a number of R scripts scheduled to run in windows. they have been running smoothly for months until a few days ago. Executing the scripts from the scheduler produces the following error:

```
Error in load(name, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
Calls: sys.load.image -> load
In addition: Warning message:
file '.RData' has magic number 'X'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated 
Execution halted
```

I suspect the trigger of this situation is the hard drive that got filled up and freeing space didn't suffice to correct this situation.
PS:

- I use two versions of R and both were affected by this situation.
- Manually executing the same scripts is working fine.
- (update) switching from bin/R.exe to bin/Rscript.exe on the scheduler makes it functional again. but I still need to go back to R.exe to produce log files locally..

Comment: For those looking for the exact syntax to use the response with scheduler:  @echo off
"C:\Program Files\R\YourRVersion\bin\R.exe --no-restore --no-save" CMD BATCH C:\YourScriptPath\YourScript.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an odd `.RData` file lying around in the directory from which the script is being executed (the “working directory”).

Delete that file.

Furthermore, reconfigure your scheduled jobs to run `R --no-restore --no-save` to prevent these files from being created or loaded in the future.